# What is "Segmentation fault" in Vowpal Wabbit?

Tags: vowpalwabbit

I have a data of 80,000,000 x 30 entries. I am trying to train a VW model with these inputs -

```
vw mydata.vw -f model1.vw --binary --sgd --passes 2 -c
```

But it is giving me error after running over the data-

```
finished run
number of examples = 1556368
weighted example sum = 1.55637e+06
weighted label sum = 0
average loss = 0.00119509
best constant = -6.42522e-07
total feature number = 14475842
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: Segmentation fault, is a memory-access violation, which usually means a bug.  See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault - Can you share your data, or part of it.   Even better: can you provide a fully reproducible example with a smaller (subset) of the data?  Also: does it happen when you add `-k`?  Also note that the output says 1.5M and you say 80M.  Could it be there's some bad input after 1.5M examples?

Comment: Sorry, I checked the data again, it is around 800,000 x 30.  I can't share the data, its confidential, but all entries are numeric. When I use `-b` option with it, it runs fine, this I don't understand.

Comment: I tried the above command line, with various data-sets but couldn't reproduce.  Also note that I suggested `-k` (to clear the cache before running as cache is sometimes not binary compatible when upgrading versions) not `-b`.  If you can reproduce, please narrow it down (minimal data, minimal options that still cause the problem, a small subset of the data is fine as long as it can trigger the problem) and share full command line and data so others can reproduce too. Without being able to reproduce it is almost impossible to help further.